# Start Page for "Opera for Android"

Tags: opera-browser

The problem: I am trying configure my "Opera for Android", the "full" browser for the Android OS, to start at the "Speed Dial", and not at the last loaded website page.  This is an issue of saving data traffic.  I run a website where some pages are long lists, which I don't want reloaded the next time I start Opera.  Yes, I know I could (and do if I remember) close Opera by clicking on the red O, and pick "exit".  This works to close all tabs, but I would like to not have to be dependent on my remembering.  Any help will be appreciated.

I have found no answer for this issue. Usual search results are for everything else other than "Opera for Android".  My apologies if I missed an answer somewhere for "Opera for Android".

The "Opera Forum" is not usefull, because, again, all answers are not for the Category "Opera for Android". Also, this question is not for Opera-Mini.